# Crop image with OpenCV

Tags: iphone, opencv

I have a problem with cropping image using OpenCV library on iPhone. I have an image with selected area and I'd like to crop image with this area. But the new image isn't map to rectangle and the new image has also blue color of text.

I use that code to crop image:

```
    IplImage *src = [OpenCV CreateIplImageFromUIImage:image];


NSValue *val = [corners objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p1 = [val CGPointValue];
val = [corners objectAtIndex:1];
CGPoint p2 = [val CGPointValue];
val = [corners objectAtIndex:2];
CGPoint p3 = [val CGPointValue];
val = [corners objectAtIndex:3];
CGPoint p4 = [val CGPointValue];

float minX = fmin(fmin(p1.x, p2.x), fmin(p3.x, p4.x));
float minY = fmin(fmin(p1.y, p2.y), fmin(p3.y, p4.y));
float maxX = fmax(fmax(p1.x, p2.x), fmax(p3.x, p4.x));
float maxY = fmax(fmax(p1.y, p2.y), fmax(p3.y, p4.y));

CGFloat width = maxX - minX;
CGFloat height = maxY - minY;

IplImage *dst = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), 8, 3);

p1 = CGPointMake(p1.x - minX, p1.y - minY);
p2 = CGPointMake(p2.x - minX, p2.y - minY);
p3 = CGPointMake(p3.x - minX, p3.y - minY);
p4 = CGPointMake(p4.x - minX, p4.y - minY);

IplImage* cropped = cvCreateImage(cvSize(width, height), src->depth, src->nChannels);

cvSetImageROI(src, cvRect(minX, minY, width, height));

cvCopy(src, cropped, NULL);
cvResetImageROI(src);
cvReleaseImage(&src);

CvMat* mmat = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);

CvPoint2D32f *c1 = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(4 * sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));
CvPoint2D32f *c2 = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(4 * sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));

c1[0].x = p1.x;   c1[0].y = p1.y;
c1[1].x = p4.x;   c1[1].y = p4.y;
c1[2].x = p2.x;   c1[2].y = p2.y;
c1[3].x = p3.y;   c1[3].y = p3.y;

c2[0].x = 0;   c2[0].y = 0;
c2[1].x = width;   c2[1].y = 0;
c2[2].x = 0;   c2[2].y = height;
c2[3].x = width;   c2[3].y = height;

    mmat = cvGetPerspectiveTransform(c1, c2, mmat);
cvWarpPerspective(cropped, dst, mmat, CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cvScalarAll(0));
```

I will be grateful for any help.

Comment: Why do not you try to see the cropped image without using the warp?

Comment: The selected are can not to be a rectangle. It can be any quadrilateral and I'd like to crop the image to that quadrilateral first and then map that quadrilateral to rectangle. But with the above function I can only crop image to rectangle area and warping doesn't work good.

Comment: how we detect corners? can you provide me guidelines or little bit code?

Comment: Gryphon, I am using OpenCV library and there you can find a function CvHoughLines2. Give me email or something then I can send you what I have, but that solution is not perfect, but I dind't find how to do that other way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had an error in my code. If someone is interested here is working code:

```
IplImage *src = [OpenCV CreateIplImageFromUIImage:image];

IplImage *dst = cvCloneImage(src);
dst->origin = src->origin;
dst->nChannels = src->nChannels;
dst->depth = src->depth;

cvZero(dst);

NSValue *val = [corners objectAtIndex:0];
CGPoint p1 = [val CGPointValue];
val = [corners objectAtIndex:1];
CGPoint p2 = [val CGPointValue];
val = [corners objectAtIndex:2];
CGPoint p3 = [val CGPointValue];
val = [corners objectAtIndex:3];
CGPoint p4 = [val CGPointValue];

CGFloat width = src->width;
CGFloat height = src->height;

CvMat* mmat = cvCreateMat(3, 3, CV_32FC1);

CvPoint2D32f *c1 = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(4 * sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));
CvPoint2D32f *c2 = (CvPoint2D32f *)malloc(4 * sizeof(CvPoint2D32f));

c1[0].x = round(p1.x);   c1[0].y = round(p1.y);
c1[1].x = round(p4.x);   c1[1].y = round(p4.y);
c1[2].x = round(p2.x);   c1[2].y = round(p2.y);
c1[3].x = round(p3.x);   c1[3].y = round(p3.y);

c2[0].x = 0;            c2[0].y = 0;
c2[1].x = width -1;     c2[1].y = 0;
c2[2].x = 0;            c2[2].y = height - 1;
c2[3].x = width - 1;    c2[3].y = height - 1;

mmat = cvGetPerspectiveTransform(c1, c2, mmat);
free(c1);
free(c2);

cvWarpPerspective(src, dst, mmat, CV_INTER_LINEAR+CV_WARP_FILL_OUTLIERS, cvScalarAll(0));

cvReleaseImage(&src);
cvReleaseMat(&mmat);

UIImage *newImage = [OpenCV UIImageFromIplImage:dst];
cvReleaseImage(&dst);
```